# Java script not working on application page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have wrote a java script to replace the value of email field to "user name" same time when user tying in the email field and I hided the username field.

Used string builder to render the script

```
function change(){
var Email=document.getElementByID('#Email');
var UserName=document.getElementByID('#UserName);
UserName.value=Email.Value;
}
```

the above code is working only when I add the webpart inside sharepoint page,but when I added the web part on an application page the UserName field is not getting updated when email field is typed.

when checked browser debugging I cant see the java script in that application page .

can I how to work this is application page ,Do I need to copy the same script to the application page where I added the webpart?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `getElementByID`. Also, there are unclosed strings. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There was two problems here, the first, getElementById wasn't written well and second, value property is lowercase.

```
function change(){
  var Email = document.getElementById('#Email');
  var UserName=document.getElementById('#UserName');
  UserName.value=Email.value;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I did it write in coding and its working in sharepoint pages .Its my typo error when I entering the code in this forum. my question is in application pages do i need to add the scrip and also need to add the string builder in application page.cs?In my application page there wont be any email and username id's i ma just adding the webpart to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 : it should be "getElementById" not <strike>getElementByID</strike>
Issue 2 : The id should not have # until and unless you are using the ID that has #(sounds silly to use # in Id)
Issue 3 : it should be "value" not <strike>Value</strike>

Use an IDE like visual studio and you will not get these silly errors.